# How to solve the travelling salesman problem using linear least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, reference-request, soft-question, least-squares

Do there exist any algorithms only using linear least squares to try and solve the travelling salesman problem? It somehow seems like such a hard problem it would not be possible to do...

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. A solution to the traveling salesman problem is a set of edges, while least squares outputs a line of best fit (which is continuous).

Comment: You are free to represent your data any way you want.

Comment: Assuming $P \neq NP$, TSP is not poly-time reducible to linear regression, because the former is $NP-HARD$ and the latter is in $P$.

Comment: You can have as big a vector as you want and represent the data any way you want.

Comment: If you drop the poly-time constraint, then you can make the reduction do all the work without needing to use regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because assuming $P \neq NP$, TSP is not poly-time reducible to linear regression, because the former is $NP-HARD$ and the latter is in $P$.

If you drop the poly-time constraint, then you can make the reduction do all the work without needing to use the regression. In other words, you can make all the $y$ coordinates the same, encoding the solution to the problem.